# How to change the date picker style in Material UI X Data Grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

How can I change the style such as colour of the default date picker in the MUI X Data Grid? It seems I can change column, cell, menu and other parts' style, but cannot change the date picker's. Why they don't use the MUI DatePicker instead of using current one? How can I access the element to change the style?

This is the default date picker:[image: default data grid date picker]

This is what I want(MUI date picker): [image: MUI X date picker]

Comment: This has been fixed, just reference: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4909#issuecomment-1136076870